# Open an .EPM file on a Mac

Tags: macos, encryption, macbook-pro

I have an a CD from work encrypted with Check Point End Point encryption software for windows. If I was trying to open this on a Windows computer I would just open the included .exe file on the CD and enter my password but as I am on a Mac is there anyway to open the .EPM file itself?

Thanks

Comment: Obviously if there's no official Mac version of the program and the format is proprietary and copyrighted (which it most likely is), there's no way unless someone has hacked/reverse engineered it, at which point due to its very nature the program becomes useless.

Comment: http://www.checkpoint.com/products/full-disk-encryption/#features Mac OS X (10.4.5 – 10.4.11, 10.5.0 - 10.7) ? A bit out of topic, but I like the expert like Steve Ballmer ))) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FhWtJ2OwZ4A